# Cannot figure out how to return part of the view and not all of it

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, view

I am trying to call a view but not all of it. I've done it before on accident but I cannot remember how I did it and do it again.

Here is and example of what I am showing:

[image]

I'd like to ONLY show the area where the red circle is at.

Here is the code:

```
public ActionResult Logon()
{
  return View();
}
```

Simple really, but I've `return PartialView();` but that didn't change it.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check your partial view if it sets the layout

something like

```
@{
     Layout = "views/shared/sitelayout.cshtml";
}
```

If it is a partial view then you can (probably) remove this

If you dont see this line you might have a default layout inheritance and need to remove that. then try this instead

```
@{
     Layout = null;
}
```

Comment: My view doesn't have anything in it but hmtl and a few @Html.DisplayFor but no layout.  Thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 2):

In the ASP.NET MVC, the default template has a page called Layout.cshtml and it is used as a base View to other Views render inside this layout where `@RenderBody()` method is called. It is defined in _ViewStart.cshtml page and is applied to all Views automatically. If you want to render a View without a Layout page, you have to set null to the Layout property of your View.

```
@{
   Layout = null;
}
```

But, remember you have to add some html layout to get a right html if your view does not have. Something like this:

```
@{
   Layout = null;
}
<html>
<head>
   <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
<body>

// content view

</body>
</html>
```

You, also can use the Html.RenderPartial method to render a view inside another one:

```
@Html.RenderPartial("YouPartialFileName")
```